# Where to get log4j2 configuration properties complete list

Tags: log4j2

I am looking for a **complete list of properties supported by log4j2**. The log4j2 documentation at following link gives only a subset of properties.
https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html#Properties

```
For ex:
Delete files older than 30 days 
appender.rolling.strategy.delete.ifLastModified.age = 30d
```

This is not listed in the manual. Any suggestions where I can find the list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A full list of all log4j2 properties does not exist because configuration with properties is only one option among many (XML, JSON, YAML etc.).

Each log4j2 part is described with a list of configurable parameters it supports (e.g. https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/appenders.html#RollingFileAppender). The URI you are linking describes the rules which property names you have to choose to configure the parameters.

So the way you have to go is:

1. Select which function you have to use (e.g. RollingFileAppender)
2. Read the chapter of this function and select the parameters you want to configure
3. Use your linked URI to create you property based configuration with the property names for the parameters you want to configure